# How to organize classes in pyqt GUI programming

Tags: python, class, oop, pyqt4, qt-designer

I have constructed a main window GUI using qt designer and pyqt. As the program grows more complex, using only one class may result in too many methods and attributes to manage. I figured that I should construct new classes in order to make things more manageable.

My first question is, how do I know when do I add a new class for my application? Is there any rule of thumb as a general guide? Is it a good idea to add a new class for new windows/tabs?

My second question is, if I added new classes for my application, how do my new class gain access to the Ui_MainWindow design file that I designed in Qt designer? Below is the sample code for my main window. Its a simple clock which displays the current time. Lets say if I would like to create a class for the clock display itself, how can I rewrite the code using OOP efficiently?

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui
from myMainWindowUI import Ui_MainWindow

class MyMainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.Time)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.Date)
        self.timer.start(1000)
        self.lcdNumber_time.setDigitCount(8)
        self.lcdNumber_time.display(strftime("%H"+":"+"%M"+":"+"%S"))
        self.label_dynamic_date.setText(strftime("%Y"+" "+"%B"+" "+"%d"+", "+"%A"))

def Time(self):
    self.lcdNumber_time.display(strftime("%H"+":"+"%M"+":"+"%S"))
def Date(self):
    self.label_dynamic_date.setText(strftime("%Y"+" "+"%B"+" "+"%d"+", "+"%A"))

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)  # A new instance of QApplication
form = MyMainWindow()                 
form.show()                         
app.exec_()
```

Comment: Before I give an answer, can you update your question with an example of what kind of things you expect to be able to access from your UI file, in another class? I want to make sure I give a specific answer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @jdi. I have added an example code of what I wanted to achieve.

Comment: I've updated my answer to mention custom signals

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, this isn't necessarily a Qt-specific problem. It isn't necessarily a python-specific problem either. You could extend this question to any language that supports class-based programming, or even any language with functions.

It makes sense to write a class when you want to encapsulate behavior. A class should usually provide a single purpose, and expose an interface to the outside that allows users of the class to interact with exactly the behavior you have designed. Once you have this single-purpose class, you now have reusable behavior. You could apply part of this reasoning to functions, where you say a given function has a specific purpose and once you design it to do the one bit of behavior, you now have a reusable function.

Applying this to Qt, it would make sense to move code into its own class when its logic is no longer trivial. An example would be where you are first creating and showing a [`QMessageBox`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmessagebox.html) from your main window. But then at some point you need to collect more types of information, and even pass some initial information in when you construct the dialog. While you could construct this on the fly in your main window, as needed, it would be better to move it into its own dialog class, with its own private logic of how to be constructed. Then you just instantiate one as needed, passing it the expected parameters to its constructor. Now your main window no longer has to also be concerned with constructing special dialogs.

Another point (which wasn't exactly clear from your question) is that Qt Designer UI files each represent a single class. It is expected that this UI definition will be applied to a single class in code. It would be bad design to have `ClassA(UI_mainWindow)` and `ClassB`, and have `ClassB` access members of `ClassA` or know anything about the internal implementation of `ClassA`. Back to our topic of "[separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)", `ClassB` should have its own purpose and interface, and be used by the `ClassA(UI_mainWindow)` to achieve that purpose. You don't want `ClassB` knowing anything about the main window or being able to do more than its designed purpose.

Let's assume your timer example was actually more trivial than you have shown it to be. If you moved it to another class, you should rely on custom signals to communicate intentions back to other classes like the main window. Or you could move each of the lcd and label widgets into their own custom classes with their own timer logic that made them self contained. Either way,  signal/slot lets custom widgets connect with each other without needing to know anything about the other widgets.

In summary, you could say that it would be good to create individual classes in Qt when you are constructing any non-trivial UI elements in another class (when it requires many lines of code, or it requires a bunch of SLOT functions and wiring for internal logic). This will keep you from repeating your logic, and allow you to have reusable code. It will also keep your main window smaller and easier to debug, since you can keep a smaller mental model in your brain of what the main window is doing. If you try to keep your UI elements as single-purpose focused and generic as possible, you will end up having a lot of classes that can be reused.